# Upper and lower bounds for $\log(\frac{n}{n-1})$

Tags: inequality

If we have a value $x>1$ and a constant $c$ then by making $k=O(\log x)$
we have

$$x\cdot (1-c)^k \leq 1$$

Now, if $c$ is not a constant, but a function such as 1/n, what is the smallest k for which

$$x\cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^k \leq 1$$ ?

Clearly an easy computation gives the value

$$k \leq \frac{\log(1/x)}{\log (1-\frac{1}{n})} = \frac{\log x}{\log{\frac{n}{(n-1)}}}$$

The problem is that I have no intuition for the magnitude of the value 
$\log \frac{n}{(n-1)}$ nor for the value of $\log(1-1/n)$.

Are there nice functions f(n) and g(n) that under-approximate and overapproximate the function $log(\frac{n}{n-1})$?

In other words, whare are the easiest to manipulate and accurate functions 
f(n) and g(n) such that

$$f(n) \leq \log(\frac{n}{n-1}) \leq g(n)$$ ?

obs: x is a function that depends on n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the bounds $$1-\frac{1}{x}\leq \log(x)\leq x-1$$ for all $x>0$. For $x=\frac{n}{n-1}$ these become $$\frac{1}{n}\leq \log\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)\leq \frac{1}{n-1}.$$

Comment: Thanks for Clementine C and Will Jagy for the other answers. I'm accepting this one because it has the simplest bounds.

Comment: No worries -- but for the record, Clementine is a woman's name (or a fruit, depending on the context), Clement is not :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write $\ln\frac{n}{n-1} = \ln(1+\frac{1}{n-1})$ and use $\ln(1+x)\leq x$ (for $x>-1$).

Answer (score 0):

For $1 > t >0$ we find
$$\frac{1}{1+t}= 1 - t + t^2 - t^3 \pm \cdots$$
which is an  alternating series with terms strictly decreasing in absolute value.

$$ \log (1 + t) = t - \frac{t^2}{2} + \frac{t^3}{3} \mp $$
with the same coments, so $1 > t > 0$ we get
$$  t- \frac{t^2}{2} < \log (1+t) < t  $$

In your case 
$$ \frac{n}{n-1} =  \frac{n-1}{n-1} +  \frac{1}{n-1} = 1 +  \frac{1}{n-1}  $$
 and
$$ t = \frac{1}{n-1}  $$

For greater accuracy just use more terms from the alternating series for $\log(1+t)$